# Print custom field in user edit form in block

Tags: users, blocks, hooks

Following code prints user edit form in block:

```
function notifikacie_custom_block_info() {
 $blocks['user_profile'] = array(
   'info' => t('User profile edit'),
   'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
 );

 return $blocks;
}

function notifikacie_custom_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

      global $user;
      module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
      $block['subject'] = t('Fill your profile');
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user);

  return $block;
}
```

But it does not print custom fields created in admin/config/people/accounts/fields. How do I print those custom fields?

Comment: from `admin/config/people/accounts/display` manage your filed, make sure that your fields not `hidden` .

Comment: It is visible, I mean, I am trying to print edit form, not print the fields itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your code and it works fine. Maybe it is permission related problem.

```
<?php
function user_profile_block_info() {
 $blocks['user_profile'] = array(
   'info' => t('User profile edit'),
   'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
 );

 return $blocks;
}

function user_profile_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

      global $user;
      module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
      $block['subject'] = t('Fill your profile');
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user);

  return $block;
}
```

Output/result:
*Here **Birth Date** is custom field, created form* `admin/config/people/accounts/fields`.
[image]